# Perfect forwarding in std::make_unique<SomeWrapper<T>> not quite perfect

Tags: c++

Given the following types:

```cpp
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;

    Point(int x, int y) : x{ x }, y{ y } { }
};

class Widget
{
public:
    std::string name;
    Widget(std::string name) : name{ name } { }
};

template <typename T>
struct DataHolder
{
    T value;

    DataHolder(T value) : value {value} { }
};
```

Why does this code compile:

```cpp
auto compiles = std::make_unique<DataHolder<int>>(42);
auto alsoCompiles = std::make_unique<DataHolder<std::string>>("Hi");
```

and this code does not:

```cpp
auto doesnt = std::make_unique<DataHolder<Point>>({20, 21});   // C2672 'std::make_unique': no matching overloaded function found    and    C7627   'initializer list': is not a valid template argument for '_Types'
auto alsoDoesnt = std::make_unique<DataHolder<Widget>>("Hello");   // C2664 'DataHolder<Widget>::DataHolder(T)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [6]' to 'T'
```

How does `std::make_unique<SomeWrapper<T>>()` determines if `T` can be constructed within `SomeWrapper`? What makes `int` and `std::string` special in this case? How can I make my types work the same way?

Comment: `DataHolder` doesn't forward the arguments of c-tor to the actual c-tor (try something like `template <typename... Args> DataHolder(Args&&... args) : value {args...} {}`).

Comment: Both answers now have the example you asked for, so I'll not repeat them. The idea is that you probably want to delay any conversion and pass arguments all the way to the last (deepest) constructor. To work around brace initialization, for `Point`, you can use `std::make_unique<DataHolder<Point>>(20, 21)` (like what you had in the unedited question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does this code compile:
>
> ```
> auto compiles = std::make_unique<DataHolder<int>>(42);
> auto alsoCompiles = std::make_unique<DataHolder<std::string>>("Hi");
> ```

`DataHolder<int>` has a constructor taking `int`, and `42` is passed as the constructor argument to construct `DataHolder<int>`, which works fine (similarly as `DataHolder<int>(42)`).

`DataHolder<std::string>` has a constructor taking `std::string`, and `"Hi"` is passed as the constructor argument, it could convert to `std::string` implicitly, which works fine (similarly as `DataHolder<std::string>("Hi")`).

> and this code does not:
>
> ```
> auto doesnt = std::make_unique<DataHolder<Point>>({20, 21});
> auto alsoDoesnt = std::make_unique<DataHolder<Widget>>("Hello");
> ```

`std::make_unique<DataHolder<Point>>({20, 21})` doesn't work because braced-init-list like `{20, 21}` doesn't have type, template argument deduction for `std::make_unique` fails on it. This belongs to [non deduced contexts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts).

> 6. The parameter P, whose A is a braced-init-list, but P is not `std::initializer_list`, a reference to one (possibly cv-qualified), or a reference to an array:

`DataHolder<Widget>` has a constructor taking `Widget`, and `"Hello"` is a `const char[6]` which could decay to `const char*`, then two user-defined conversions are required, one from `const char*` to `std::string`, one from `std::string` to `Widget`, but only one user-defined conversion is allowed in one implicit conversion sequence. (Similarly `DataHolder<Widget>("Hello")` doesn't work either.)

If you pass `Point` and `std::string` directly, they would work fine.

```
auto doesnt = std::make_unique<DataHolder<Point>>(Point{20, 21});;
auto alsoDoesnt = std::make_unique<DataHolder<Widget>>(std::string{"Hello"});
```

As [@YiFei suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67667215/perfect-forwarding-in-stdmake-uniquesomewrappert-not-quite-perfect/67667303#comment119605081_67667215), you can make `DataHolder`'s constructor template, and forward all the arguments by `std::forward` to the constructor of `T` to initialize the data member directly, i.e. work in the similar way as `std::make_unique`.

E.g.

```
template <typename... Args>
DataHolder(Args&&... value) : value {std::forward<Args>(value)...} {}
```

Note that `std::make_unique<DataHolder<Point>>({20, 21});` still doesn't work for the reason above. But you can do `std::make_unique<DataHolder<Point>>(20, 21);` instead, `20` and `21` are forwared to the constructor of `Point` taking two `int`s and then works fine. Similarly for `std::make_unique<DataHolder<Widget>>("Hello")`, `"Hello"` is forwarded to the constructor of `Widget` taking `std::string`, `"Hello"` could convert to `std::string` implicitly and then works fine.

Comment: The `Point` being sent as 2 arguments was a typo, I just updated my post, sorry about that. Still does not compile though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's very helpful! Is there a way to modify `DataHolder` to further pass through the arguments, as per @YiFei's suggestion on my original post? I don't fully understand their suggestion though

Comment: @CoolBots Answer revised.

Answer (score 3):

`std::make_unique<DataHolder<Widget>>("Hello")` requires two conversions, one from `const char*` to `std::string` and another to `Widget`. Only one implicit conversion is allowed.

`std::make_unique<DataHolder<Point>>(20, 21)` doesn't work because it's would be the same as calling `DataHolder<Point>(20, 21)` but `DataHolder` only takes a single argument.

Your first two examples only require a single or no implicit conversion so work.

To make these work you need `DataHolder` to forward its constructor arguments to `value`:

```
template <typename ...Args>
DataHolder(Args&& ... args) : value {std::forward<Args>(args)...} { }
```

Comment: The Point being sent as 2 arguments was a typo, I just updated my post, sorry about that. Still does not compile though